# Ajax PHP - Check returned response/data value from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically, I am validating a sign-up form and calling a php script with ajax to check if an email address already exists or else the query executes. If an email address already exists (checked with a count query), I am echoing an error back to the ajax function (via response) - however it is not being read.

I tried researching similar topics but no luck.

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'signup-user.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {

                        if(response == "error-email-exists"){
                            $('#errorMsg').html("An account is already assosciated with the email adress you entered.");
                            $('#errorMsg').hide().stop(true,true).fadeIn(600);
                        }else if(response == "success"){
                            window.location = "index.php";
                        }else{
                            $('#errorMsg').html(response);
                            $('#errorMsg').hide().stop(true,true).fadeIn(600);
                        }


                }
            });
```

**php**

```php
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include("conn.php");

    $post_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $post_lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $post_dateofBirth = $_POST['dateofBirth'];
    $post_gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $post_propertyNo = $_POST['propertyNo'];
    $post_propertyAddress = $_POST['propertyAddress'];
    $post_streetAddress = $_POST['streetAddress'];
    $post_locality = $_POST['locality'];
    $post_email = $_POST['email'];
    $post_password = $_POST['password'];


    $checkexistsQuery = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(*) AS countExists FROM tbl_account acc WHERE acc.email = ?');

    $checkexistsQuery->bind_param('s', $post_email); 
    $checkexistsQuery->execute();

    $checkexistsQuery->store_result();
    $checkexistsQuery->bind_result($countExists);
    $checkexistsQuery->fetch();

    if($countExists > 0){
        echo 'error-email-exists';
    }else{
        $signupQuery = $conn->prepare('insert into tbl_account (name, surname, email, password, dob, genderID, propertyNumber, propertyAddress, streetAddress, localityID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        $signupQuery->bind_param('ssssssssss', $post_firstName,$post_lastName,$post_dateofBirth,$post_gender,$post_propertyNo,$post_propertyAddress,$post_streetAddress,$post_locality,$post_email,$post_password); 

        if($signupQuery->execute()){
            echo 'success';
        }else{
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }


    }

?>
```

The problem is that 'error-email-exists' and 'success' messages are not being read.

Comment: What do you mean it's "not being read"?  What specifically is happening?

Comment: If there is really a new line before `<?php` then some datas are sent before anything (and the response will be different than `'error-email-exists'`

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: Write next to `success` block an `error: function(error) { console.log(error)}` block to be sure `success` is entered.

Comment: Check that there's no whitespace being returned, as this will break your `response == "error-email-exists"` check. It's for this reason it's much better practice to return a serialised response format. A quick fix would be `response.trim() === 'error-email-exists'`, however I'd suggest using JSON instead to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: write the `error: function(data){ //your code }` in your ajax code afer success function for other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code as below. Use json type as `contentType` and add an `error` method to your ajax. With json you will be more flexible and have the opportunity to add structured data like errors, messages and even markup.

js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'signup-user.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            $('#errorMsg').html(response.message);
            $('#errorMsg').hide().stop(true, true).fadeIn(600);
        } else {
            if (response.exists) {
                $('#errorMsg').html("An account is already assosciated with the email adress you entered.");
                $('#errorMsg').hide().stop(true, true).fadeIn(600);
            } else {
                window.location = "index.php";
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

php:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include("conn.php");

    $post_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $post_lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $post_dateofBirth = $_POST['dateofBirth'];
    $post_gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $post_propertyNo = $_POST['propertyNo'];
    $post_propertyAddress = $_POST['propertyAddress'];
    $post_streetAddress = $_POST['streetAddress'];
    $post_locality = $_POST['locality'];
    $post_email = $_POST['email'];
    $post_password = $_POST['password'];


    $checkexistsQuery = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(*) AS countExists FROM tbl_account acc WHERE acc.email = ?');

    $checkexistsQuery->bind_param('s', $post_email); 
    $checkexistsQuery->execute();

    $checkexistsQuery->store_result();
    $checkexistsQuery->bind_result($countExists);
    $checkexistsQuery->fetch();

    $response = [];
    $response['error'] = false;

    if($countExists > 0){
        $response['exists'] = true;
    }else{
        $signupQuery = $conn->prepare('insert into tbl_account (name, surname, email, password, dob, genderID, propertyNumber, propertyAddress, streetAddress, localityID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        $signupQuery->bind_param('ssssssssss', $post_firstName,$post_lastName,$post_dateofBirth,$post_gender,$post_propertyNo,$post_propertyAddress,$post_streetAddress,$post_locality,$post_email,$post_password); 

        if($signupQuery->execute()){
            $response['exists'] = false;
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Edit: This does not work accordingly and is returning : http://prntscr.com/p7p0ub on console

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo missing `$` -> `echo json_encode($response);`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! One quick question - is the response['error'] ambigious since if errors are handled by **error: function(error)**??

Comment: No. This name is up to you. `function(error)` fires when the response status is not 200 (error by the server e.g. status 500).